# How to select data with a complex condition?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using Microsoft Access, I normally use condition (mostly `where`) to obtain the data I want to display.

So far, it went well. However now I have a complex filtering and I'm not sure of the best way to do it. I will explain how I do it with many queries, and I'd like to know if there is something simpler, since I feel like it's doing too much for what I accomplish.

I have `Building` and `Energy` tables. Between them, I have a link table since a `Building` has a list of possible energies.

My goal is to display ALL energy not already associated with the building.

I first have a simple query to display all the IDs of energy that are in the link table where building is the one of interest.

Once I do that, I have another query using this one, which display an energy if it is an energy absent from previous list.

This takes 2 queries and I feel like I could have a better way to do this. I'm fairly new to MS Access, so any suggestion is welcome.

Here is the first request to obtain the list of energies:

```
SELECT 
    Batiments.ID, Energies.ID, Energies.Type 
FROM 
    Energies 
INNER JOIN 
    (Batiments 
INNER JOIN 
    Batiment_Energie ON Batiments.ID = Batiment_Energie.Batiment_ID) ON Energies.ID = Batiment_Energie.Energie_ID 
WHERE 
    (((Batiments.ID) = " & cbxBatiments.Column(0) & "));"
```

Comment: Please show the queries. It is difficult to tell you what you can do better without seeing what you have done so far.

Comment: added the first request, will add the  second one shortly, I realised I made a mistake for the second one

Comment: Try a not in statement...select * from table1 where column not in (select column from table2)

Comment: John Kane thanks, if you mean where not... it will give me all the energies since there is at least one entry in the link table between both for the enerny for another building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the non-associated energy types with

```
SELECT
    ID, Type
FROM
    Energies
WHERE
    ID NOT IN (SELECT Energie_ID
               FROM Batiment_Energie
               WHERE Batiment_ID = 123)
```

where `123` is to be replaced by the Id comming from `cbxBatiments.Column(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from energie as e
where not exists (select 1
                  from Batiment_Energie as be
                  where be.energie_id = e.id and be.batiment_id = <your id>
                 );
```

Comment: so far it returns nothing

Comment: That would mean all energies are used for that select id. Please post data so we can demo solutions for you.